# invalid parameter number , parameter no defined

Tags: pdo

Trying to insert data in database , but php throwing invalid prameter number ,

```
$stmt =$pdo->prepare('    
INSERT INTO '.$_POST['option'].' 
(id,title,description,image,date,city,user,price)
values (null,:titl,:desc,:img,:dte,:cty,:user,:prce)');

$stmt->execute( array(
    ':titl'=>$_POST['title'],
    ':desc'=>$_POST['description'],
    ':img'=>$item_img,
    ':dte'=>$date,
    ':city'=>$_POST['city'],
    ':user' =>$_POST['name'], 
    ':prce' =>$price,));
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Wow! A table name right from the POST? You are a risky guy. Why bother with preparing your data though?

Comment: While error itself is clear. You've got a typo in your placeholder name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is an extra `,` at the very end after `$price` and also the `:cty` typo. Try the following:

```
$stmt->execute(
    array(
     ':titl' => $_POST['title'],
     ':desc' => $_POST['description'],
     ':img' => $item_img,
     ':dte' => $date,
     ':cty' => $_POST['city'],
     ':user' => $_POST['name'], 
     ':prce' => $price
     )
    );
```

Comment: this answer is irrelevant to the question and wrong by itself

Comment: I have changed that

Comment: yeah i have seen it thanks